# restrict user to enter values in the url to redirect

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net

I know this would be the basic and quite repetitive over coders. 
I would like to disable the URL field for the logged in user, so that he will no more edit it manually to redirect to any particular page.

Comment: You mean you want to block browser's address bar? Not possible. You can try to open a window without the address bar, but that might be blocked by user preferences.

Comment: So what are the possible ways to restrict user to manually edit the browser bar?

Comment: The browser belongs to the user. He should have the loyalty to do anything. But the web app belongs to you. So, you have to restrict the access to any page/URL. Ex: User may change URL parameters -> You can restrict GET methods and force to use POST methods.

Comment: Thank you Chandpriyankara. A best example would make me understand the behavior. Suggest me some links to understand it.

Comment: I can hear a weak "security" approach sneaking...